# How to load css file and make webview editable in jetpack compose

Tags: css, webview, android-jetpack-compose, edit

In common implementation with xml files I'm using RichTextEditor with implementation of webview.

But I can't fined similar implementation for jetpack compose and I decided to use native webview as editor and encaunter some problems.

How to load css file and make webview editable in jetpack compose ?

```
val webViewClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                return true
            }
            override fun onReceivedHttpError(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?,
                errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?
            ) {
            }
        }
    }
val chromeViewClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebChromeClient() {
            override fun onCloseWindow(window: WebView?) {
                super.onCloseWindow(window)
            }
        }
    }
```

Creation of webview

```
WebView(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                state = urlState,
                onCreated = { webView ->
                    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                },
                client = remember { webViewClient },
                chromeClient = remember { chromeViewClient }
            )
```